# Apple watch battery drain very fast with full max capactity

Tags: battery, apple-watch

I got a new Apple Watch Ultra 3 months ago. During the last half-month, I have not worn it and recharged it regularly. In the first 2 months, I can use it without recharging for two days at least.

Recently, its battery consumption becomes very fast, and even cannot keep a record of my sleep for a whole night (~7hrs). However, Battery Health shows the max capacity is still 100%. I am wondering if it is normal or not. I also turned off always on screen and some notifications, also the OS is up to date. What are the possible issues?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would take it to an Apple Store for a diagnosis.

Comment: Your only option is to take it in as @benwiggy said.  First, it's still under warranty, second, only Apple can address as there's no CLI interface like macOS, and third, if there's an issue with an OS update, they need to know about it.

Comment: @Allan, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @benwiggy, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you [Restarted](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/restart-apple-watch-apd521a8a902/watchos) the Watch?

Comment: @IconDaemon, I will try to restart it. I guess i need to observe my Watch's performance for one day?

Comment: @IconDaemon, my Watch's battery still drains very fast after restarting both the Watch and my iPhone...

Comment: I had a Watch v. 3 that drained the battery fast. I sent it in to Apple (it was past warranty period) and they -fixed- it for US$99. (I think they just sent a refurbished one.) You're best bet is to contact Apple if it is still under warranty.